# How to scrape the data using requests module only in python

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler, http-post

I am actually trying to parse a website using the requests module, and extract some text out of it.

Url : https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx

after hitting the url in the Cp Number text field input : 16803

hit search,

on the bottom you can see some data, I want that data, let's say a name.

I am successfully able to get the data using selenium, but can't able to get it using requests module.

I have tried the requests module giving parameters, sessions, cookies etc. 
but nothing worked.

```
url = "https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx"
ss = {'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber':'16803',
      '__EVENTTARGET':'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch',
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'6A295697',
      'dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$Search':'SiteRadioButton'}

session = requests.Session()
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()

for cookie in cookies:
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

response = requests.post(url, data=ss)
print(response)

HTMLTree = html.fromstring(response.content)

name = HTMLTree.xpath('//div[@class="name_head"]//text()')

print(name)
```

I expect the output of the name of the person.

Anyone out there please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using C# code I would be more than happy to help you otherwise it's a very lengthy process. If you choose that python is the only road you're willing to take then you should try grabbing the encrypted value within C:\User[USERNAME]\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies You can change the file path accordingly to your OS. You can use SQLite to read and modify the encrypted values.

```css
cookie = Decrypt(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(SQLDatabase1.GetValue(i, "encrypted_value")
if (cookie.Contains(".ASPXANONYMOUS")): 
    Step1 = cookie + "END"
    Step2 = (step1 + ".ASPXANONYMOUS")
```

The following code above may help you with your journey.